# Best way to cover up this hole drilled when installing a ceiling fan?

Tags: trim, wood-filler

So I installed a ceiling fan intending to cover up the wire holes with trim. As you can see below the holes drilled were too big. The entire house uses this size and type of trim. It would look weird putting larger trim here.

Would filling the hole with wood filler be a viable solution? Would the wood filler interact poorly with the fan wiring?

[image]

Comment: What type of wiring is that? Non-metallic cable? Lamp cord (plug type wiring)? Low voltage wiring?

Comment: 3-wire for ceiling fan. 14awg

Comment: Is the trim going to be painted white?

Comment: If it is not armored, running it under molding rather than the wall cavity is probably a code violation, and more importantly, a risk of damage and danger.

Comment: I am going to add the protective metal conduit to the wiring. The trim is going to be stained.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't common on an open wall, more for shadow boxes and such. However, you could remove that piece of molding and cut another piece with a 45° angle where it meets the corner. Then cut a small piece about 1ft. long with 45° angles on both ends. Then cut yourself a dead end on the left side. You will probably have to cope the excess wood at the corners for the wire to fit better. You can pinch nail both pieces at the top and bottom for a tight fit in that area.

[**Crown Molding Return**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yd0ze7kd3g)

[image]